# How to use data-cy in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I am trying to use `data-cy` to use to check the heading of text but as it uses `v-for`, cypress test can't find the text and instead give a failing test as it wasn't able to find an exact match.

```
it('first line contain heading', ()=>{
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/')
    cy.get('[data-cy="book-heading"]')
      .invoke('text')
      .should('equal', 'In Search of Lost Time')
})
```

[image: error]
[image: DOM]

How can use cypress to get the right text?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot for the error along with the screenshot of the Dom?

Comment: @AlapanDas I have updated the question with error and screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
it('first line contain heading', () => {
   cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/')
   cy.get('[data-cy="book-heading"]').contains('In Search of Lost Time')
})
```

Comment: thanks. what if I want a second heading, will it scan the whole page for the keywords?

Comment: If you have multiple occurrences of `data-cy="book-heading"]` on the page, you can access them by using `eq()`, something like `cy.get('[data-cy="book-heading"]').eq(0).contains('In Search of Lost Time')` or `cy.get('[data-cy="book-heading"]').eq(1).contains('In Search of Lost Time')` etc.